# How to extract the argument from an in-built function

Tags: expression-manipulation

I would like to extract the argument from :

```
DiracDelta[-10 + x + ξ]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Part` to access the parts of any normal expression.

```
DiracDelta[-10 + x + ξ][[1]]
(* -10 + x + ξ *)
```

In this case you can also use `First` since you want the first part.

Another common need is to pull out the arguments of a function when that function is buried in a larger expression.  For this you can use `Cases`

```
Cases[
 {w''[z] + k^2 w[z] == DiracDelta[z], w[0] == 0, w'[0] == 1},
 DiracDelta[arg_] :> arg, Infinity]
(* {z} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
DiracDelta[-10 + x + \[Xi]] /. DiracDelta -> Identity
(**)
```

More generally(also works for several arguments)

```
 Apply[List ,DiracDelta[-10 + x + \[Xi]] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DiracDelta[-10 + x + \[Xi]] /. DiracDelta -> " "
```

or (as @JasonB wrote):

```
First@DiracDelta[-10 + x + \[Xi]]
```